# copy a linked list... without using clone

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to write a class method to copy an existing linked list without using clone. my data in the original list is:

```
3 8 -1 5 12 4 -3 7 0 10 3 6 9 -2 5 11 -6 -4 -2 -1
```

the issue is that im getting a new list with 20 nodes full of -6. my method is as follows:

```
public SortedLinkedList copy(){

    SortedLinkedList copy = new SortedLinkedList();

    Node ptr, nodeBefore;

    copy.start = new Node(start.data,null);
    ptr = start.next;
    nodeBefore = copy.start;

    while(ptr != null){
        nodeBefore.next = new Node(start.data, null);
        nodeBefore = nodeBefore.next;
        ptr = ptr.next;
    }
    return copy;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this looks like homework, I'll just give you a hint. The problem is in this statement. What data are you putting into the next node?

```
nodeBefore.next = new Node(start.data, null);
```

Comment: D'oh. thanks, it is for Homework, and thank you for the hint. much better than just blindly copying code. its not start.data i wanted, its ptr.data.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you keep creating the nodes with the same start data.

Also, reconsider your variable names. How about calling `nodeBefore` `prevNode`?

Another point you could have added is the implementation of your Node class.